ESP32 Functionality Test
I am building a Bluetooth RFID encoder for hotel key cards. Below are the components that I have purchased and put together. There are pictures of the circuit as well.

ESP32 Development Board
PN532 NFC Module
1200mAh LiPo Battery
Adafruit Micro-Lipo Charger
Low-Profile Headers
JST Connectors
Jumper Wires
Breadboard

The next step is ESP32 functionality test on Arduino IDE. I've connected ESP32 with my computer (Mac OS) and selected the correct board, which is ESP32 Dev Module, but I can't find the correct port, which should be /dev/ttyUSBx or /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART.
I've tried installing CP210xVCPDriver for Mac OS, but I still can't find the correct port.
What could be the problem here? Please let me know!

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't appear to be related to programming and is therefore off-topic

There are ESP32 modules available which have a different UART controller than the CP210x. I know there are also then CH9102 and the CH340.
I don't know MAC-OS but on windows the device manager shows a second after connecting, a new com port device. Make sure your computer detects the ESP32 before you try to flash with the Arduino IDE
